possible to define local type alias in function using generic param?
This apparently isn't allowed
struct Foo<T>(T);
impl<T> Foo<T> {
  fn foo(self) {
    type VecOfMe = std::vec::Vec<Foo<T>>;
  }
}

here I'm trying to define VecOfMe simply as a shorthand (in a real-life example the full type is much larger), not trying to do any trickery with it. Is this possible / why not? The reasoning in What is the rationale for not being able to use the outer type parameter within an inner function? doesn't seem applicable - I'm not defining any inner function/constant/etc, just a local type alias.
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6a7453b82dcc0f5bda6c5e6507ac5fcd

If you only have a small amount of parameters, a workaround is to use type VecOfMe<T> = Vec<Foo<T>>; and write VecOfMe<T> instead. It appears that type statements just don't use scope for some reason.

You still can use type to create a shorter alias, but just can't hide the generic parameter away, so this would work (note that VecOfMe has to be VecOfMe<T>, which is not too much verbose):
struct Foo<T>(T);
impl<T> Foo<T> {
  fn foo(self) {
    type VecOfMe<T> = Vec<Option<Result<Foo<T>,std::io::Error>>>;
    let _v: VecOfMe<_> = vec![Some(Ok(Foo::<u32>(42)))];
  }
}

Playground
